# Why won't web_reg_find see certain static text in LoadRunner?

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

Why won't web_reg_find see certain static text in LoadRunner? Even when I use the 'Find Text' tool while recording, it throws an error.

Comment: Could you give some details that we can help you with your problem. Telling us there is a problem doesn't help you reach the solution. What error do you get? What is the text in the HTML you are trying to find? Please fix the question if you want someone to help.

Comment: Is it possible you are asking the question in the wrong location?  Consider the web_reg_ function set like a sieve, through which you pour the HTML and the value you are seeking is left when the page has been filtered.   It is common to place this after the page load, thinking that it will work on a previously loaded buffer.